# Is this functional jointly continuous in the measure and the integrand?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, signed-measures

Let $\Delta[0,1]$ be the space of all signed Borel measures over $[0,1]$, ranging between -1 and 1. $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is the set of all functions with domain $[0,1]$ that takes values in $[0,1]$. Consider the functional $V: \Delta [0,1] \times [0,1]^{[0,1]}, V: (\mu,f) \mapsto \int fd\mu$. My question is, is $V$ continuous in $(\mu,f)$? Or, what additional conditions do we need for it to be?

Background: I'm trying to apply the [Maximum theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem), where my objective function is of the form $\int fd\mu$.

Comment: I guess $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ should consist only of measurable functions. Anyways, what topology do you want to put on these spaces?

Comment: I'm so sorry I missed your comment yesterday. Yes, sorry only measurable functions. Weak-* topology on $\Delta[0,1]$ and $L^1$ on $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$, I think. Sorry for the imprecision. I'm an econ PhD student and have had to try to learn all this math on my own, for my research. :(

Comment: In that case, I'm sorry that the answer will probably be bad news. Btw: Almost everyone in economic theory would take $\Delta[0,1]$ to be the space of Borel probability measures on $[0,1]$, and not a space of signed measures.

Comment: But I need it to be the space of signed measure for the specific problem I'm working on!

Comment: Sure, but you could use some new notation that doesn't have such a fixed meaning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we put the weak$^*$-topology on $\Delta[0,1]$, then $V$ cannot even be jointly measurable, independently of the $\sigma$-algebra put on $[01]^{[0,1]}$. We can embed the unit interval $[0,1]$ as a subspace of $\Delta[0,1]$ via the embedding $x\mapsto \delta_x$. But the question has a negative answer on this smaller space too, the function $e:[0,1]\times [01]^{[0,1]}\to [0,1]$ given by
$$e(x,f)=f(x)=\int f~\mathrm d\delta_x$$
is not jointly measurable, independently of the $\sigma$-algebra put on $[01]^{[0,1]}$. This follows from a [deep result](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/%7Eraumann/pdf/66.pdf) of Aumann.

There is a positive answer if we endow $\Delta[0,1]$ with the weakest topology such that the function $\mu\mapsto\mu(A)$ is continuous for every measurable set $A\subseteq [0,1]$ and $[01]^{[0,1]}$ with the uniform topology given by the metric $d(f,g)=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$. This follows from the fact that the simple functions, measurable functions that take on only finitely many values, are dense in $[01]^{[0,1]}$. However, $\Delta[0,1]$ is not metrizable and also not compact. The latter means one cannot apply the maximum theorem here. The topology on $\Delta[0,1]$ is also not metrizable, but the finer topology given by the [total variation of signed measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation) is. But under this finer topology, $\Delta[0,1]$ is, of course, still not compact.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! Let me ask my original question in a different way elsewhere. Thank you again!

Comment: Also, are there any other ways of showing continuity that you would suggest, given that Berge's theorem fails?

Comment: I don’t think there is a general alternative. If you have a very specific problem, there might be other structure that xan be used.